# Findbugs .fbprefs config using excludefilter from jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

In my Findbugs .fbprefs file in Eclipse I want to define an excludefilter but the xml filter file is located in a jar file.

I want to do something like that:

```
...
excludefilter0=C:/Projects/myjarfile.jar/findbugs/excludefilter.xml
...
```

Is there any possibility to do that?

Already tried many things but nothing worked for me.

I am using Eclipse Findbugs Plugin v. 3.0.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse+FindBugs - exclude filter files doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568579/eclipsefindbugs-exclude-filter-files-doesnt-work)

Comment: It's no duplicate. I've got a problem in adding an excludefilter which is in a jar-file. The other question is about a simple xml excludefilter.