# What is the difference between "Settings..." and "Default Settings..." in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, settings

I find I can set File Encodings and other parameters in both `File` | `Settings...`, and also `File` | `Other Settings` | `Default Settings...`. However, I'm not clear on what the difference between these two options is.

Further, I can run `File` | `Export Settings...` to save settings to a settings.jar file, however I am unclear what is restored if I run the `File` | `Import Settings...` operation.

- What is the difference between the two settings options?
- What settings are being exported/imported when running export/import?

[image: Android Studio Menu options in File menu]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The settings in Android Studio work the same way as they do in the IntelliJ IDE, as [Android Studio is based on IntelliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/05/15/intellij-idea-is-the-base-for-android-studio-the-new-ide-for-android-developers/).

### Settings

`File` | **`Settings`** is used to [define settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-settings.html) that apply for the current project, and also settings for the IDE (i.e. not related to, or saved with, a project).

In the *Settings* dialog, settings are grouped into (1) "Project Settings" for the current project (which may change when a new project is loaded), and (2) IDE Settings which are not specific to the current project:

[image: Settings]

### Default Settings

`File` | `Other Settings` | **`Default Settings...`** apply only for [new projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-default-settings.html) (the template project's settings).

Thus if a new project has just been created, then Default Settings and Settings would be the same.

Note in the dialog that the settings are labelled "Template Project Settings", and include the same sub-headings as those for "My Application" from *Settings*, above:

[image: Template Project Settings]

### Exporting and Importing Settings

Settings may be [**exported** to a JAR file](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/exporting-and-importing-settings.html#1), such that they may be [**imported**](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/exporting-and-importing-settings.html#2) later.

#### Exporting

When importing and exporting, one or more components may be selected to import or export. **Default Project Settings** (those accessible from `File` | `Other Settings` | **`Default Settings...`**) is one of the options available for export/import. In the dialog below, only Default Project Settings are selected for export:

[image: Exporting default settings]

#### Importing

When an exported JAR settings file is selected for import, in the "Select Components to Import" dialog, only options that were originally exported are available for re-import. In this case, only Default project settings were exported, and thus this is the only option to select when re-importing the file:

[image: Only Default Project settings available]

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean I can't import and export Default settings to a JAR file?

Comment: @HelloCW If you start a new project (which uses default settings), then immediately export settings, then you'd have exported the default settings.

Comment: Thanks! I hope that I can backup and restore Default Settings , is it possible?

Comment: @HelloCW Yes, this is indeed possible. I've updated my answer to describe this process.

Answer (score 1):

**Export settings** : You can export your favorite IDE settings as jar file.

In the Export Settings dialog box that opens specify the settings to export by selecting the check boxes next to them. By default, all settings are selected.

[image]

**Import Settings** : Similarly you can import settings to your IDE

**Default Settings** : These settings are used as defaults every time you create a new project.